# How to redirect login page without loading master layout in MVC using form authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

When form authentication timeout occurs, my page automatically redirects to the login page, but it opens within the master layout.  How can I reload my login page without loading the master layout as it loads first time?

Comment: How do you do the redirect?

Comment: Please provide some more context in your question.  Provide code samples and show what you have tried and why they haven't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add this on top of the Login cshtml (assuming you're using Razor):

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```